# How to push specific commits to svn using `git svn dcommit` instead of entire set of commits?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

```
commit5 master
commit4
commit3
commit2 git-svn
commit1
```

If this the scenario, `git-svn` is where svn is at. What if I want to push only commit 3 but not commit 4 and 5 yet, how do i achieve this?

`git svn dcommit --interactive` doesn't help. It stops if i say no for commit 4

then it should later look like:

```
commit5 master
commit4
commit3 git-svn
commit2
commit1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it was fairly simple.

```
git checkout commmit3
git svn dcommit
git checkout master
git svn rebase
```